# Event handling with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, event-handling

Ok so, this is quite confusing to explain. I will try my best.

Inspired by the Bukkit Event System where you can make voids an event handler by just using @EventHandler.

Example:

```
@EventHandler
public void aRandomName(PlayerMoveEvent ev) {

}
```

As you can see, the name of the method doesn't matter. Which event is passed on is determined by the event argument type.

All events extend the Event class.
I have made up some code which I think would work, except for one thing.

```
public List<Object> eventContainers;

public void fireEvent(Event e) {

    Method[] methods;

    for (Object o : eventContainers) {
        Object[] classes = o.getClass().getClasses();

        for (Object clss : classes) {
            methods = clss.getClass().getMethods();
            for (Method m : methods) {
                if (m.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class) != null) {
                    try {
                        Class[] requiredTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
                        for(Class cl : requiredTypes) {
                            if(e.equals(cl)) {
                                m.invoke(clss, e);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What my code does:
Loops through all the classes in eventContainers, looks for methods that have the @EventHandler annotation and sends the specified event to that method. However, I want to see what kind of event the given event in fireEvent(Event e) is, and then look at the methods who require an event parameter of that kind. How would I do that? I figure that

```
Class[] requiredTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
for(Class cl : requiredTypes) {
  if(e.equals(cl)) {
    m.invoke(clss, e);
  }
}
```

will not work.

Ultimately I want to be able to pass on events to plugins. Like this:

```
EventManager.fireEvent(new PlayerMoveEvent(player));
```

Which will be sent to all plugins and the plugins that have

```
@EventHandler
public void aVoid(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
//stuff
}
```

If you have any questions, I will try to explain it better. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses `e.equals(cl)`, which is comparing an instance of `Event` with an instance of `Class` (the class of an instance of `Event`) - this will never return true. What you want to do instead is:

```
if(e.getClass().equals(cl)) {
    m.invoke(clss, e);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want methods annotated with `@EventHandler` to handle all subclasses of the class that their method signature defines (i.e. a method like `handle(Event e)` would be called with `PlayerMoveEvents` as well as all other events), then you want:

```
if(cl.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
    m.invoke(clss, e);
}
```

See the [`Class` Javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) for more information.

Note that I think there are a few other problems in you code. For example, `Method.invoke` should be called with an instance of the class that contains a method that is annotated with `@EventHandler`. It is a little unclear from your code, but I believe this should therefore be:

```
m.invoke(o, e);
```

Also, by calling `o.getClass().getClasses()`, you are iterating over the classes defined in the class of `o` - you probably want to iterate over the methods of the class of `o` directly, i.e.:

```
for (Method m : o.getClass().getMethods()) {
    if (m.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class) != null) {
        Class[] requiredTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
        if (requiredTypes.length == 1 && requiredTypes[0].isAssignableFrom(e.getClass()) {
            m.invoke(o, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameter types from a `Method` using `method.getGenericParameterTypes()`, so:

```
m.invoke(clss, m.getGenericParameterTypes()[0].class.cast(e));
```

Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: By looking at that piece of code, it seems like you try to cast the event e to the parameter required in the method. If it cannot be done then it will not be sent? (as in exception catching) I think this is what I'm looking for. Thanks alot!

Comment: That is what I do, cast the event to the parameter required. You can use normal try/catch blocks for exception handling. See InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `EventHandler` annotated method only has one parameter

```
Method[] methods = YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
Object yourInstance = null; // get it
Event e = null; // get it
for (Method method : methods) {
    EventHandler handler = method.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class);
    if (handler != null) {
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        // you're going to need different logic if you have more than one parameter
        if (parameterTypes.length == 1 && parameterTypes[0].isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
            method.invoke(yourInstance, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've not included any exception handling.

Get all the methods of event handler candidate classes and iterate over them. If a method has the `@EventHandler` annotation, get its parameter type list. If it only has one parameter and that type is assignable from your event type `e.getClass()`, then invoke it passing in your event.

Answer (score 0):

I have now modified the code to a working event system!!!!!! :D thanks so much andersschuller!

```
public void fireEvent(Event e) {

    Method[] methods;

    for (Object o : eventContainers) {
        methods = o.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class) != null) {
                try {

                    if (m.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
                        m.invoke(o, e);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I kept all answers in mind, thanks all!